# How to preserve csv data when using read_csv and to_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to aggregate several csv files into one.
After the aggregation I notice that pandas tries to do a float estimation even if i state that the datatype should be a string. Works for most cells, however, in some cases pandas adds many trailing zero's or nine's as it would be a float. The main goal would be to preserve the raw data as i just want to aggregate the files on top of eachother into one file.

How do i prevent pandas to do add float numbers and instead preserve the input data?

Raw data from column

```
Column - Sales

-3.145
-111
-1.418
-3.453
```

Generated Output in csv

```
Column - Sales

-3.1450000000000004
-111.0
-1.418
-3.4529999999999997
```

Expected output

```
Column - Sales

-3.145
-111
-1.418
-3.453
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=(';'), dtype={'Sales':str})
li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame.to_csv("sales.csv", mode='a')
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I tried that, and got the same result unfortunately. Thank you

Comment: Not sure about this, but it may be the engine. Have you tried setting ```engine = 'python'``` in your read_csv parameters? If I understand how it works correctly, the C engine (default) optimizes by assuming values are numeric wherever possible, which is faster. However, in the process it may convert to numeric and back again, at which point your string data gets really long.

Comment: @philosofool Thanks for your input, Yes i tried that as well, still same result.